# Laravel Mix - Public CSS Keeps overriding

Tags: css, laravel, sass, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel mix in my project. I need to alter the app.css in the public folder, whenever i comment or delete styles and run npm run dev the styles come back. I need them gone. How do I permanently stop this?

Comment: You are definitely doing something wrong. Write where exactly are those styles?

Comment: app.css / app.js are generated and compiled everytime you run npm run dev. If you want to alter that you can check the assets folder. or you can just create your own css/js file in the public folder.

Answer (score 1):

The files in `public` generated by `npm run [production|dev]` are compiled versions of the application's source files. These files should be treated as immutable: they are written once during the compilation process and never to be written to again. Any changes you need to make to the output should be done in the compilation process, whether that's by modifying the source files *or* by adjusting the way that the compilation process works. Every time you run `npm run dev` it replaces the old files with the new.

You can find the source files for your application in [`resources/assets`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/resources/assets). If you're not sure how to make a specific change please create a new question outlining the problem you're having, e.g: "I want to remove this style from my `app.scss` but I don't know how".